# How to capture contents between headers of an HTML page?

Tags: java, android, http, httpurlconnection

I am seeing something strange to me, but maybe normal to experts.  The only way to explain it is reporting my observation.

Wireshark was used to capture the response from a server to a CGI command (essentially an HTTP GET command) as following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 35
Date: Thu, 19 Jan 2017 04:38:07 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.20

admin, Administrator
user1, Group1

Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8

<html>
<head>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</head>
<body>
request invalid html file.</body>
</html>
```

Browser Chrome shows the following:

```
admin, Administrator user1, Group1
```

This is like magic to me.  I do not know how Chrome ignores the HTML content "request invalid html file", and displays the desired contents embedded among header.

The Java code of an Android app gets the following from the same CGI HttpURLConnection:

```
<html>
<head>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</head>
<body>
request invalid html file.</body>
</html>
```

This is what I would expect, but I want to the same magic as Chrome does - displaying the contents embedded in headers.  Please note they are **not** headers.  Is there a way to do it without resorting to a socket?
**[Edit]**
The following is the Java code for reading the response (nothing special):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
String line;
StringBuilder sbResponse = new StringBuilder();
// read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sbResponse.append(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
br.close();
```

Comment: It's using the 35 bytes (from the `Content-Length:`) after the the two newlines after the `Server: lighttpd/1.4.20` line.

Comment: Does it mean that HttpURLConnection of Java does not handle it correctly?  I am going to edit the question to add the Java code.

Comment: If you're seeing the `<html>` bit, it looks like you're getting the second document transferred on the HTTP connection.

Comment: The response is from one GET command.  I did not post the GET command part sent from Chrome or the app.

Comment: Try it in a webview. Browsers were designed to handle poor HTML in a variety of ways.

Comment: My end goal i is reading the contents in an Android app and process them accordingly.

Comment: You're right, they are not headers, they are invalid HTTP. Fix the server.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have to live with this server.